# Extract Value from a String? (JSON expression)

Tags: r, json

I want to extract the value (.68) from this string.
How would I go about doing this?

```
{"values":[{"source":"source_value","value":".68"},    
{"source":"source.units","value":"%"},
{"source":"source_name","value":"Chemical"}]}
```

Currently, I have tried:

```
sub(".*:", "", df$value_as_string)
```

But I only get:

```
"\"Chemical\"}]}"
```

Comment: This looks like you have data encoded in JSON format. Why not use a JSON parser to extract the data rather than a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you. Im not too familiar with JSON formats, so if you have any good links on how I can parse out the value, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) package is another option.

```
library(jsonlite)

# note the single quotes to wrap the double quotes
j <- fromJSON('{"values":[{"source":"source_value","value":".68"},    
               {"source":"source.units","value":"%"},
               {"source":"source_name","value":"Chemical"}]}')
```

Now `j$values` is a data frame. Note that the value "0.68" is type character, not numeric.

```
j$values  
        source    value
1 source_value      .68
2 source.units        %
3  source_name Chemical

j$values$value[1]
[1] ".68"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **jsonStrings** package to manipulate JSON strings:

```r
x <- '{"values":[{"source":"source_value","value":".68"}, {"source":"source.units","value":"%"}, {"source":"source_name","value":"Chemical"}]}'

library(jsonStrings)

jstring <- jsonString$new(x)

jstring$at("values", 0, "value")
# ".68"
```

Explanation: `"values", 0, "value"` is the path to `".68"`. First the `"values"` key, where we found an array, then `0`, the first element of this array, then `"value"`, the key of `".68"`.